# Evolution is deleting emails from my inbox

Tags: email, evolution

Every now and then Evolution deletes emails from my inbox. Once it occurred when I emptied the trash, but other times it simply removes incoming email after was viewing incoming email.

Unlike the other person's post, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Evolution (3.10.4) using POP3 accounts (two email accounts).

Anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Which other person's post?

Answer (score 3):

Evolution checks for junk. That's like checking for spam, except it's done by your client (Evolution), not by your provider (for example Google). So check the folder `Junk` to find your emails (and maybe move them to your inbox).

You might also have different folders in which your emails provider sorts incoming emails because he wants to categorize them into communication, shopping, banking, forums, newsletters, notifications, you name it. You should see these folders in Evolution. However, emails aren't downloaded until you first use such a folder, so keep an eye on the bottom bar to see if it's downloading something because this might be a reason you don't see emails if you click through the folders quickly.